# pathname translation in Emacs for finding local source file path from remote (ssh compile) error filenames

Tags: windows, emacs, cygwin, compile-mode

Is there some sort of general pathname-rewriting/normalizing facility I can exploit in Emacs to allow source files in compile-mode to be translated to local paths based on remote paths?  I was hoping to use symbolic links, but that's not working for me in Windows.

I'm running GNU Emacs 23.1.1, and have tried cygwin-mount and w32-symlinks.el (with `(customize-option 'w32-symlinks-handle-shortcuts)`); I can't get open-file/dired/completions OR compile-mode next-error to follow either windows shortcuts or cygwin symlinks.

I'm remotely compiling (over ssh) and the warnings/errors give filenames where a prefix of the absolute pathnames (e.g. `/nfs/topaz`) on the remote host needs to be replaced with a different path (`z:/`, in fact), which I was hoping to do with symbolic links.

`/` does go to (gets tab-expanded to in emacs) `c:/cygwin` and `~` to `z:/` (my `$HOME`).

What I'm hoping for is either: a fix for symlink resolution (tab completion or opening a windows shortcut gets me the .lnk file and not what it points to), or the ability to supply a list of rewrites for prefixes of pathnames.  Junctions aren't an option because the replacement path I want is on a different drive (it's also a Samba mount).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is also useful in other complicated build environments:  I use OpenWRT, and the build process copies (or extracts) source code to a separate build directory in which compilation occurs.  So naively following file names in the emacs compilation buffer leads to edit the temporary copies, not the originals.  Dangerous.

Comment: Coming back to this, I've found that abusing the `directory-abbrev-alist` variable [see manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Directory-Names.html) solves my problems better.  In essence, you can tell emacs that compilation directory name is an alias ("abbreviation") for the source directory, so when it encounters a path in the compilation directory it re-writes it to be one in the source directory.

Consider also ["Magic Filenames"](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Magic-File-Names.html) and the hook `file-name-handler-alist`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a partial solution:

```
(custom-set-variables '(compilation-search-path (quote (nil "z:/dir1" "~/dir2"))
```

etc.  Of course, I have to add dozens of paths, but it's a huge improvement (next-error actually works now!)

Answer (score 0):

After re-reading a few times, I still am not quite sure what your situation is -
Are you compiling remotely and editing locally? If so, it seems like you should try doing both tasks on the same machine, or maybe try [tramp](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode) mode in emacs.  I just don't see an easy way to translate a remote path to a local one.

Comment: The remote host has as some local canonical absolute path prefix what is locally a samba mount, namely `z:/`.  As I said, they really are the same files.  I did use tramp a long time ago.

Comment: I use emacs on my windows machine because my cygwin xserver doesn't support subpixel fonts (cleartype).